# The absence of an article in "it's always been challenge"

Tags: articles

Is it actually grammatical to do without an article before "challenge" here:

A road, it's always been challenge
That's what can bring you a lot of grieve.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am concerned, those are both ungrammatical. There may be varieties of English that allow one or both of them, but I'm not familiar with any such.

The second one appears to be an error for *grief*. The first one, I have no idea what it is trying to say.